# How to parse and detect a block of lines from a log file in perl ?

Tags: arrays, perl, parsing

I have a file looks like this

```
[
MsgName:XYZ
Status:Pass
]

[
MsgName:ABC
Status:Pass
]

[
MsgName:bbb
Status:Fail
Error
]

[
MsgName:ttt
Status:Pass
]
```

Now I want to read this file and create  2 log files 
One Regular LOG containing all the data and other Error LOG containing the Data with only Error in it

so in this case error log should show only

```
[

MsgName:bbb

Status:Fail

Error

]
```

and regfular log everything

Can anyone guide me how to do this

I tried this way

```
while($line[i]=<FileHandle>
{

if($line[i]=~ /^s*\]/)
{
  print OUT "recd new msg-->:/n $line[i];
  next;
}
do

{
  print OUT "$line[i]";
  if($line[i]=~ /Error/)

{  ####this section i cannot figure out hw to frame it  get my desired output

   print "error found

   print ERROROUT .....

} until($line[i]=~ /^s\]
```

here i use OUT for regular log output
and ERROROUT for error log

Comment: Just to add I want the entire block of error msg and not just the Error line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest trick is to store the entire block you are interested, in a fifo while you are traversing the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

my @fifo=('') x 5; # Initialize an empty array with size = 5 (Message Block Size)
open(FILE,"log.txt");

while(<FILE>)
{
    push(@fifo,$_);       # Add element to the end of array making its size 6  
    shift @fifo;          # Remove first element reverting its size back to 5  
    if($fifo[3]=~/Error/) # Check if 4th line of block has error in it 
    {
        print @fifo;
    }
}
close(FILE)
```

Comment: Any other ways rather than storing and checking....do you have any way to check simultaneously while travsering

Comment: This code doesn't store the entire file if that is what you are asking.It only memorizes five last lines while traversing the file. So in essence it is checking while traversing.